# A year long Schengen visa but I have passed the three months maximum stay

Tags: visas, schengen, business-travel

I have been granted a Schengen visa for one year with the condition of staying a maximum of 90 days in Spain back in April, now, I have exceeded that period without calculating. I flew out of Spain for work but then returned, I got held in the airport because the police did calculate how long I stayed and did not allow me in.

I hold a Saudi passport and my visa is still valid until April next year, can I "refresh" my visa to enter Spain again? As I have another work trip before the date that I will be allowed to enter Spain again.

Comment: When did you leave the Schengen area? When did you try to come back?

Comment: They would have made a memorandum entry in your passport.  What does it say?

Answer (score 9):

If you stay in the Schengen zone for 90 days, the only way you can qualify for an additional 90-day stay is by leaving and remaining outside the zone for 90 days.  You can't be in the Schengen zone for more than 90 days in any 180-day period.

This answer discusses the recently-revised rule: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/21461/19400.  Another answer to the same question links to a calculator: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/27123/19400

However, now that you've been refused entry, you may have bigger problems.  What did they stamp in your passport when they refused you?

In theory, if your work requires you to be in the Schengen zone for more than 90 days in a 180-day period, you should have applied for a different kind of visa.  You may be able to make such an application now, though I would suspect that your recent overstay will make it more difficult for your application to succeed.